# Was Pablo Vicente de Solá married?

Tags: spain, colonial-america, marriage, mexico, california

Solá, a Basque, was the last Spanish governor of Alta California, serving from 1815–1822 at the Presidio of Monterey. Did he have a wife and family, there or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the site [Leinztarra](https://sites.google.com/site/leinztarra/sola), Solá was married to Nicolasa Sufriategui Arangoitia, with whom he had a son, Antonio Vicente Solá Sufriategui, born 1778.

Donald Nuttall's 1972 paper "The Gobernantes of Spanish Upper California: A Profile", concludes that he was not, but perhaps failed to uncover this detail.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

In [California Through Russian Eyes, 1806–1848](https://books.google.com/books?id=uZOjAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=pablo%20vicente%20de%20Sol%C3%A1%20daughter&source=bl&ots=Hd-cEy5F2o&sig=sDRjQrvNxZgX3FbHxTJOLXSBKoM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGrruTlJDQAhXF2SYKHdIGB4AQ6AEIRzAM#v=onepage&q=pablo%20vicente%20de%20Sol%C3%A1%20daughter&f=false), on page 158, there is a discussion of a celebration being held in honor of the Tsar's birthday. Entertainment in the form of dancing and singing caused mention of two young girls 'sweet voices'. One of the girls who 'distinguished herself' is listed as *Dona Josefa de Sola*.  The footnote credits her as 'The daughter of Governor *Pablo Vincente de Sola*'.

That is the only indication of family (besides his brother) that I find.  Since he died in Mexico City in 1826, perhaps records might be found there, such as a will or burial site near other kin.

Comment: That is indeed suggestive; thank you for the reference.

Comment: I now believe that Gillsen was mistaken about Josefa's relationship to the governor. He says Solá and Commandant Arguello were brothers, which is clearly wrong. I cannot find any other reference to Josefa.

Comment: The mission records at the Early California Population Project show that Josefa Arguello Bernal was the Commandant's niece and goddaughter, baptized in San Francisco and twelve years old at the time Gillsen visited. I think it is likely he misunderstood about her relationship to the governor.